# Error attempting to use elasticsearch-grails-plugin: getting java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, grails, grails-plugin, grails-4

I'm running grails 4.0.1 attempting to use org.grails.plugins:elasticsearch:3.0.0 with elasticsearch 7.9.0. I'm not sure if I've misconfigured a bean along the way that I'd missed but any help in the right direction would be well received! Near ready to drop using the plugin if can't get it wired in my env but would like to keep up with it.

More complete trace contains

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'grails.core.support.proxy.DefaultProxyHandler' to required type 'grails.core.support.proxy.EntityProxyHandler' for property 'proxyHandler'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'grails.core.support.proxy.DefaultProxyHandler' to required type 'grails.core.support.proxy.EntityProxyHandler' for property 'proxyHandler': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:590)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertForProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:604)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:219)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1723)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1679)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1426)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
        ... 49 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'grails.core.support.proxy.DefaultProxyHandler' to required type 'grails.core.support.proxy.EntityProxyHandler' for property 'proxyHandler': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
        at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:262)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:585)
```

Comment: If you are unsure, whether you have mis-configured something, it would help to add what you have configured beyond adding the dependency (or provide a minimal failing example). Have you found evidence, that the version of the plugin you are using is supporting Grails4 and not only Grails3?

Comment: "Have you found evidence, that the version of the plugin you are using is supporting Grails4 and not only Grails3?" - The user guide indicates that version 3 of the plugin is compatible with Grails 4 (https://puneetbehl.github.io/elasticsearch-grails-plugin/snapshot/index.html#plugin-versioning).

Comment: Please try version 3.0.0.M1 of the plugin which should fix the problem.